# Return a collection of an anonymous type with dynamic linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, dynamic-linq

Apparently, the Dynamic LINQ Library has the ability to return a collection of an anonymous type.

However, I am not exactly sure how to do this.

I basically just need to build the following using Dynamic LINQ

```
            var result = from s in Customers
                     select new[] {
                         s.Surname, 
                         s.FirstName,
                         Convert.ToString(s.CustomerID),
                         s.Gender,
                         s.Notes,
                         s.DateUpdated.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
                     };
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: That should work if you remove the `[]`

Comment: You are not using dynamic LINQ in your query

Comment: To clarify, what I meant here was what is the 'equivalent' in Dynamic LINQ

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `new[]` instead. If you want to the result to hold an array of anonymous objects then you can use `.ToArray()` at the end of the query like:

```
 var result = (from s in Customers
                     select new {
                         s.Surname, 
                         s.FirstName,
                         Convert.ToString(s.CustomerID),
                         s.Gender,
                         s.Notes,
                         s.DateUpdated.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
                     }).ToArray(); //here
```

*(This doesn't uses [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), its normal LINQ query)*

Comment: It doesn't use Dynamic LINQ.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, yes it doesn't

Comment: Thanks Habib, but I'm looking for a Dynamic LINQ example.

Comment: @jjc99, your sample query in question is not dynamic LINQ,

Comment: @jjc99, getting an array from the query would be same for both Dynamic LINQ and normal. You need to remove `[]`. Could you post your dynamic LINQ query